# NetworkOnMainThreadException while executing HTTP Request

Tags: android, mysql, http-post

I searched like the whole internet but no answer could help me.

I'm trying to get a data string out of an MySQL database but just get this `'andoid.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException'` error. Could anyone help me?

Here is my Code:

```
public String getInformationForBarcode(String barcode) {
    try {

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.example.com"); // Yes, i changed this in live code to my url with data in it
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        final String response = httpClient.execute(httpPost,
                responseHandler);
        return response.trim();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR : " + e.toString());
        return "error";
    }          
}
```

Yes, I set the

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`.

All i get is the error message in LogCat :(

Hope one of you can help me!

Thanks for answering.

Comment: possible duplicate of [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: @user3244807 : Did you call 'getInformationForBarcode()' on thread or AsyncTask?

Comment: @user3244807 : Please do not perform any network operation on main UI   thread.!!

Comment: I don't know how you "searched like the whole internet", but your error message in google yields about a bazillion answers that explain in details what is happening and why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to make connections to database it's better to do that in another thread to avoid app crash because such actions can take long time. You can use `AsyncTask` to perform those actions in the background. Check out the developers site for more information about the task http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html